# hide or disable dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm trying to hide a row or disable a dropdown when a document is approved once.
This code does the approved/rejected/pending. Now, I want to make it so that when an admin has approved a document once, then when he/she logs in again, they should not be able to approve/reject the same document again. Here is my asp.net code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string connStr = 
         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydms"].ConnectionString;
   SqlConnection mySQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
   if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
   {
      mySQLconnection.Open();
   }

   foreach (GridViewRow row in GrdFileApprove.Rows)
   {
      if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
         DropDownList DropDownListcontrol = row.FindControl("DropDownList4") as 
            DropDownList;

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("approveddd", mySQLconnection);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
         Convert.ToInt32((row.Cells[1].Text));

         cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproveID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
         Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListcontrol.SelectedValue);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproveBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =
            (Session["Login2"]);

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
      }

      else
      {
         apfi.Text = "Error";
      }
   }

   if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
   {
      mySQLconnection.Close();
   }
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `DropDownListcontrol.Enabled = false`?

Answer (score 1):

Hide dropdown:

```
DropDownList1.Visible = false;
```

Disable dropdown:

```
DropDownList1.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: i am trying this but when it shows me error "The name 'drodownlist1' does not exist in the current context" and drodownlist1 is inside in gridview..